# How to refer element id dynamically

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, myfaces, tomahawk

I am trying to spread the radio buttons using tomahawk selectOneRadio. My id looks like this

```
<rich:dataTable id="carTable" value="#{cars}" var="car">
    <rich:column>
        <s:decorate id="types" template="/layout/display-text.xhtml">
            <t:selectOneRadio id="models" value="#{car.model}" layout="spread">
                <f:selectItems value="#{models}" />
            </t:selectOneRadio>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <a:repeat value="#{models}" rowKeyVar="index">
                    <t:radio for="car:carTable:0:types:models" index="#{index}"></t:radio>
                </a:repeat>
            </h:panelGrid>  -->
        </s:decorate>
    </rich:column> 
</rich:dataTable>
```

I referred id after inspecting an element. But this is not working. Because for each iteration radio button id varies. How to refer an id in t:radio

Comment: I don't do RichFaces/Seam, but doesn't just `for="models"` work? It would have worked without them.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for t:radio](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tlddoc/t/radio.html) says:

> The id of the referenced extended selectOneRadio component. This value is resolved to the particular component using the standard [UIComponent.findComponent()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) searching algorithm.

I'm guessing `a:repeat` is a `NamingContainer`, so using `"models"` won't work. You can use the [client identifier](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId%28%29) of the `t:selectOneRadio` component.

Something like this:

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="models" value="#{car.model}" layout="spread"
   binding="#{requestScope.modelComponent}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{models}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <a:repeat value="#{models}" rowKeyVar="index">
    <t:radio for="#{requestScope.modelComponent.clientId}" index="#{index}" />
  </a:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Caveats:

1. This binds the component to the request scope map using the key "modelComponent"; you need to ensure this doesn't collide with something else
2. Resolving `modelComponent.clientId` requires JSF 2.0 (JEE6) or above

See [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html) for more details; working with older versions; etc.